is there a temporary object/variable when "int x=5;" or " int x=y+5 ;"
i have a question when i make this declaration of x
int x = y + z ;

here a temporary object is created equal to (y+z) then this temporary object will be assigned to x . (that is what i learned)
also here when calling function: fun(const int &i);
calling the function fun( x + y ) ;
my question is:
is here the same idea when
is there is a temporary object will be created to hold the 5 in two of them below ??
int x= 5 ;      // 1

fun(5);         // 2


Good viewing when you have an hour: The Nightmare of Initialization in C++

Why don’t you use compiler explorer and inspect generated code on your compiler and platform? https://godbolt.org/

Using Compiler Explorer, a fabulous tool, isn't much help here. There's a lot of stuff that could be happening in the abstract machine that has been optimized out on the way to machine code.

compilers have always implemented copy elision, usually when you think 2 objects will be created the compiler will only create one, as for the case int x = y + z; the compiler can elide the temporary, ie: y + z is calculated directly in x, it is not materialized then copied, no temporary ever existed.

"... then this temporary object will be assigned to x" - Not quite. x will be copy-initializied by the result. There won't be a temporary (unless result of y+z isn't int or a conversion needs to take place for other reasons - not sure if that temporary counts as a temporary though).

Entire papers can be written about what a temporary object is or is not and when it is or is not. In which way is it important for you?


int x = y + z ;
here a temporary object is created equal to(y+z) then this temporary object will be assigned to x . (that is what i learned)

That's incorrect. When initializing a non-class type like int from an expression of non-class type, the initializer expression is (implicitly) converted to a prvalue of the target type and that value is the initial value of the object that is being initialized. There is no additional prvalue-to-xvalue conversion that would imply a temporary object materialization.
Assuming that y and z are also of type int, then y + z is a prvalue of type int already and no conversions are required at all. There is no temporary object.

also here when calling function: fun(const int &i);
calling the function fun( x + y ) ;

Here you are correct. A temporary object of type const int is created. However, that happens only because a reference must bind to a glvalue expression. It can't bind a prvalue expression. Instead, if the initializer is a prvalue expression (of the same type), a prvalue-to-xvalue conversion, i.e. a temporary object materialization conversion, is applied. This conversion implies that a temporary object is created and the reference is initialized to refer to it.

int x= 5 ;      // 1

5 is a prvalue expression of type int. So as in the first case above, no temporary materialization conversion is happens.

fun(5);         // 2

That's the same as the second case above. 5 is a prvalue expression of type int, just like y + z, and a prvalue-to-xvalue conversion is required to bind to the reference, implying creation of a temporary object.

The whole initialization and conversion rules in C++ are quite complex. Assuming you are just beginning to learn C++, you do not need to care about any of this. It doesn't matter whether or not temporary objects are created in any of the cases you mention above. There are only few very specific edge cases where the difference would be relevant and if you are not doing something very unusual, you will not run into them.

Not just non-class types, prvalues are not objects, they initialise an object (or are discarded)

@Caleth I say specifically non-class type, because otherwise it isn't true that the initialization happens by implicit conversion. In other cases overload resolution for constructors and/or conversion functions may be done and then there will be a prvalue-to-xvalue conversion reference binding to the parameter of the used function.

If you have class Foo; then Foo operator+(whatever, whatever) creates a prvalue Foo

@Caleth Yes, and if it the result is used to initialize anything other than a Foo, then there will be a temporary object materialization from that prvalue one way or another. If the initializer expression has the same type as the variable and the initializer expression is a prvalue, yes, then there is no temporary object for either class or non-class types.

This answer makes use of some important language terms that are poorly, if at all, covered out side of the top text books and technical papers, so here's a terminology helper: What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?

In the first case (int x = 5;), no temporary object is created - 5 is directly stored in x. It's a direct initialization.
In the second case (fun(5);), a temporary object is created to hold the value 5 because the function takes a reference to a constant, and temporary values can be passed to such references.

Re: int x = 5; being direct initialization: I'd call that copy-initialization.

Before C++11... Smurf. It's 2024. DO I really have to bother?

And for anybody who cares, it's not just @TedLyngmo who'd call it copy-initialization. The C++ standard calls it that as well. For direct-initialization, you'd use something like int x{5}; instead (though in this case, where the value and the object being initialized have the same type, there's not a whole lot of difference between the two). Somewhat paradoxically, copy-initialization can actually do a move instead of a copy.

@JerryCoffin and move in this case would be just an abstraction, as in reality code is allowed formally and would just create object in place (whatever is used as automatic\temporal  storage). For complex classes it would try even to inline constructor and opeations and is allowed to optimize out everything that ddin't had observable effect.

@user4581301   You may not have to bother.   Some people are still required to.

@Peter Nah. I still have to bother. I still can't upgrade the compiler for a few projects because there's no support for the CPU after 3.3. But I can dream, right?

@Swift-FridayPie: Maybe. Without knowing the types of y and z, it's hard to be sure though.

@user4581301  We can always dream!   The joys of technical debt.
